# How to force native styling of controls?

Tags: mac-os-x, gui-construction

While preparing a dynamic module, I discovered a weird behaviour of Mathematica's controls when you rotate them:

```
Rotate[Button["Toto", Null], 0]
Rotate[Button["Toto", Null], 0.01]
Rotate[Button["Toto", Null], 0.02]
```

[image]

The first non-rotated button has standard Mac OS styling. The last one, for large enough rotation, uses a non-native styling, which is somewhat ugly. But the real surprise is that controls with small enough rotation are displayed with native styling (and it *is* actually rotated, not just rounded down to the case of the non-rotated button).

My point of view is that, while I can live with the ugliness of non-native buttons, I'd rather have uniformity between all my controls. So, my question is two-fold:

- How can I force rotated controls to be displayed with native styling?
- If that's not possible, how can I force non-rotated controls to be displayed with non-native styling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `Style` setting `ControlRendering` to display controls in their generic form:

```
Rotate[Style[Button["Toto", Null], ControlsRendering -> "Generic"], 0]
```

If you don't see the bottom line you need to set the `Buttons ImageMargins`:

```
Rotate[Style[Button["Toto", Null, ImageMargins -> 1], 
  ControlsRendering -> "Generic"], 0.0]
```

Comment: This sounds like what I was looking for, but it doesn't work for me (Mac OS 10.8, MMA 8.0.4.0) because the bottom border of the button isn't drawn :(

Comment: Adding `ImageMargins` option will make the line visible.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this:

```
 Rotate[Framed[
  Button["Toto", Null, Appearance -> "Frameless", 
   BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 16, Bold}], RoundingRadius -> 5, 
  Background -> GrayLevel[.95]], 0]
 Rotate[Framed[
  Button["Toto", Null, Appearance -> "Frameless", 
   BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 16, Bold}], RoundingRadius -> 5, 
  Background -> GrayLevel[.95]], 0.01]
 Rotate[Framed[
  Button["Toto", Null, Appearance -> "Frameless", 
   BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 16, Bold}], RoundingRadius -> 5, 
  Background -> GrayLevel[.95]], 0.02]
```

[image]

Comment: Hum, drawing my own controls… why not? The only downside I see in my first tries is that it makes the clickable area slightly smaller.

Comment: @F'x You can probably increase the clickable area with the `Button` option `FrameMargins`.